# CakePHP 3.x update multiple rows

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a table AssetsAssignations, with hundreds of rows. In some cases, the user needs to select many rows with a checkbox, and change the "status" for all of them together.

In my controller, I have this function

```
public function editMultiple()
{
    $assetStatuses = $this->AssetsAssignations->AssetStatuses->find('list');
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Assets', 'AssetStatuses', 'Clients', 'Rooms'],
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'Assets.model_number',
            'Assets.serial_number',
            'AssetStatuses.name',
            'Clients.last_name',
            'Rooms.name',
            ]
    ];

    $assetsAssignations = $this->request->data;

    $assetsAssignations_ids = array();

    foreach($assetsAssignations as $a){
        $assetsAssignations_ids[$a['id']] = $a['id'];
        $this->AssetsAssignations->updateAll(

            array('AssetAssignation.id' => $assetsAssignations_ids)
        );
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Statsus is updated for the selcted entries!'));
    }            
    debug($assetsAssignations);

    $query = $this->AssetsAssignations->find()
        ->contain(['Assets', 'AssetStatuses', 'Clients', 'Rooms']);
    $filter = $this->Filter->prg($query);
    $assetsAssignations = $this->paginate($filter, ['maxLimit' => 10000, 'limit' => 10000]);        

    $this->set(compact('assetsAssignations', 'assetStatuses'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['assetsAssignations']);
}
```

In my edit_multiple.ctp, I use a javascript to filter the data. And I put this code:

```
<table class="hoverTable dataTable">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th><th>Model Number</th><th>Serial Number</th><th>Room</th><th>Client</th><th>Status</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        </thead>
                    <?php foreach ($assetsAssignations as $assetsAssignation): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="data[AssetsAssignations][id][]" value="<?= $assetsAssignation->id ?>" id="AssetsAssignationsId1" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td><?= $assetsAssignation->has('asset') ? $assetsAssignation->asset->model_number : '' ?></td>
                        <td><?= $assetsAssignation->has('asset') ? $assetsAssignation->asset->serial_number : '' ?></td>
                        <td><?= $assetsAssignation->has('room') ? $assetsAssignation->room->name : '' ?></td>
                        <td><?= $assetsAssignation->has('client') ? $assetsAssignation->client->last_name . ', ' . $assetsAssignation->client->first_name: '' ?></td>
                        <td><?= $assetsAssignation->has('asset_status') ? $assetsAssignation->asset_status->name : '' ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <legend><?= __('') ?></legend>
    </div>
        <?= $this->Form->create($assetsAssignation) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"><?= $this->Form->input('asset_status_id', ['options' => $assetStatuses, 'empty' => true, 'label' => __('Change Status To')]) ?></div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

When I debug the result, checking 3 entries, I get this:

```
[
'data' => [
    'AssetsAssignations' => [
        'id' => [
            (int) 0 => '411',
            (int) 1 => '413',
            (int) 2 => '415'
        ]
    ]
],
'asset_status_id' => '3'
```

]

My question is: How to pass the selected row IDs to the "Submit" button after selecting the checkboxes ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put the table inside the form and the array with the ids will be passed to the action

Comment: Thanks Arilia. I put the table inside the form. But did not understand how to pass the ids in the action (I'm a beginner wth cakephp). Could you help more please ?

Comment: in your controller try and print out $this->request->data() and you'll see it contains an array of your ids.

Comment: I updated my code in edit_multiple.ctp and controller. I added the debug result.
The save did not work

Comment: I believe you need to use '_ids' as your data key, not 'id'. Your AssetsAssignations should probably also be assets_assignations. See [Converting BelongsToMany Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-belongstomany-data) in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is something like

```
if($this->request->is('post')
{
    $ids = $this->request->data('data.AssetsAssignations.id');
    $asset_status_id = $this->request->data('asset_status_id');

    $this->AssetsAssignations->updateAll(
        ['asset_status_id ' => $asset_status_id ]
        ['id IN' => $ids]
    );

}
```

Comment: I tried this:
`$ids = $this->request->data('AssetsAssignations.id');
        $asset_status_id = $this->request->data('asset_status_id');
        $this->AssetsAssignations->updateAll(
            ['asset_status_id ' => $asset_status_id ],
            ['id IN' => $ids]
        );`

I got an error message : Impossible to generate condition with empty list of values for field (id)

Comment: of course you have to check that your post data is not empty, otherwise you'll be trying to update even if no ids are checked.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this code. I put this:
 `if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $ids = $this->request->data('AssetsAssignations.id');
            $asset_status_id = $this->request->data('asset_status_id');
            $this->AssetsAssignations->updateAll(
                ['asset_status_id ' => $asset_status_id ],
                ['id IN' => $ids]
            );
        }        
        debug($ids);
`
In my edit, when I select some checkboxes, I always get: null as a result in debug($ids)

Answer (score 2):

Based on what @Arilia suggested, tis worked for me. In my controller, function, I put this:

```
    $this->request->data;
    $data = $this->request->data;
    debug($data);

    if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) 
    {
        $ids = $this->request->data('data.AssetsAssignations.id');
        $asset_status_id = $this->request->data('asset_status_id');

        $this->AssetsAssignations->updateAll(
            ['asset_status_id ' => $asset_status_id ],
            ['id IN' => $ids]
        );

    }
```

In my view, I put this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[AssetsAssignations][id][]" value="<?= $assetsAssignation->id ?>" id="ApplicationId1" ></td>
```